# iOS, stop running a function when "back" button is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, html-parsing

The application is made of navigation views.
I am calling a function in viewDidAppear which is

```
[self extractInfoWithWebsite:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.cineklik.com/%@-%@.aspx", self.cinemaType, self.location]];
```

This function does HTML parse from the a current webpage on the internet.
The code is kind of long to share but the idea is that it extract data from a website.

The problem is that I am having is that if the user decides to click the back button of the navigation before that the information is loaded, the page stays the same and the application stops functionning (not a crash but becomes static, doesn't do anyth anymore).

Is there a solution to this?
Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I changed the code to the following:
            NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

```
    /* Create our NSInvocationOperation to call loadDataWithOperation, passing in nil */
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(extractInfoWithWebsite:)
                                                                              object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.cineklik.com/%@-%@.aspx", self.cinemaType, self.location]];

    /* Add the operation to the queue */
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
```

Now I am able to press the back button without freezing, but now there is a crash with the following error:
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
I think it s because my function was still running in the background.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you actually want to 'cancel' the request? // Another solution (proces) could be that you use something like a bgthread for these kinds of "heavy-duty" actions - (When using a seperate thread, your main one doesn't lock-up)

Comment: If information is being loaded, you should disable user interaction and on completion enable user interaction.

Comment: another solution is to cancel loading data on navigating back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look up [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

The standard approach inside an NSOperation is to check if they have been cancelled before doing heavy processing.

[Here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/230146-proper-nsoperation-iscancelled-handling.html) is a good link to start your research from.

EDIT: I thought I would clarify the cancelled part

NSOperations have a main() and inside main() it is good practice to do something like

```
NSData* chunkyReply = nil;

if (!self.isCancelled) {
    chunkyReply = [NSURL stuff];
}    


if (!self.isCancelled) {
    //parse chunkyReply
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the loading code in the background using:

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#>];
```

And then you will have control of the back button pressed and you can capture it

Answer (score 0):

There are different kind of approaches, the one that fits best for me it's encapsulating the process inside a [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) that you create in ViewDidLoad and stop in ViewWillDisappear.

Another approach is to create an object with a delegate and then set the delegate nil when leaving the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a better answer without knowing exactly what `extractInfoWithWebsite:` looks like, but I'm going to assume it's split into two parts:

- Retrieve data from the URL you're passing it
- Parse that data

For the first part, if you're using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...]` or `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronoushRequest:returningResponse:error:]`, then you need to change them. Neither of these two URL-fetching methods allow you to cancel a request. Apple has [good documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) on how to use the asynchronous, cancellable methods.

Next is the parsing you're performing on the data you retrieve. Unless you're fetching a order of megabytes from the Internet, your parsing probably isn't *worth* cancelling. However, you should do the heavy lifting in a background thread anyway:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //perform parsing
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!self.view.window)
            return; //won't update UI if we've moved offscreen
        //call methods to update the UI
    });
});
```

This will perform the parsing in the default priority background queue and update the UI (any text fields, etc) in the main queue once the parsing is done.

Yes, this isn't cancellable, but like I said, unless you're handling *a lot* of data, it's probably safe not to encapsulate the parsing into an NSOperation. You'll be wasting a little bit of CPU time, but I would try this approach first and if the performance isn't where you need it to be, change to an `NSOperation` later. No sense in early optimization if it's unnecessary.